Primes which are safe and Sophie Germain
If $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime then $2p+1$ is safe prime.
If $2p+1$ is safe prime then $p$ is Sophie Germain prime.

What is their conjectured distribution of primes $p$ which are both Sophie Germain (meaning $2p+1$ is also a prime) and safe (meaning $\frac{p-1}2$ is also a prime)?

$5$ is such an example since $2$ and $11$ are both prime.
$11$ is such an example since $5$ and $23$ are both prime.
$23$ is such an example since $11$ and $47$ are both prime.
$83$ is such an example since $41$ and $167$ are both prime.

To my knowledge it has not been proven (though conjectured) that there are infinitely many Sophie Germain primes

Certainly it is not known whether there are infinitely many Sophie Germain (or safe) primes. I think you could obtain some expected asymptotics using circle method heuristics. Perhaps a good place to look is information on the prime k-tuples conjecture (or the first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture).

Sorry updated. I am just looking for conjectured distribution to predict runtimes for algorithms.

The prime $k$-tuples conjecture won't work because the spacings between such primes aren't fixed distances from one another.  You want to apply the Bateman-Horn conjecture.

This question is related to OEIS entry A059455 for safe primes which are also Sophie Germain primes.

This is asking for the density of Cunningham chains of the first kind of length three.  Take the integer polynomials $f_1(n) = n$, $f_2(n) = 2n+1$ and $f_3(n) = f_2(f_2(n)) = 4n+3$ and apply the (remarkable!) Bateman-Horn conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman–Horn_conjecture.   (The prime $k$-tuples conjecture won't work because the spacings between such primes aren't fixed distances from one another.)
EDIT: Specifically, the conjecture in this case states that the number of primes $p$ less than equal to $x$ such that $2p+1$ and $4p+3$ are also prime (so, in other words, such that $2p+1$ is both Sophie Germain and safe) is asymptotic to a constant $A$ times $\frac{x}{(\log x)^3}$, where
$$A =  \cdot 4\cdot \frac{9}{8}\cdot \prod_{p \geq 5} \frac{1-3/p}{(1-1/p)^3}.$$  In particular, if you want the number of primes $p$ less than equal to $x$ such that $p$ is both Sophie Germain and safe, then you need to substitute  $\frac{x-1}{2}$ for $x$ in the functions above, so the answer is that the number of such primes less than or equal to $x$ is asymptotic to $$\frac{9}{4}\frac{x}{(\log x)^3} \prod_{p \geq 5}\frac{1-3/p}{(1-1/p)^3}.$$
